# Use video files in Spartacus PDP page using <cx-media

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I am tyring to display a video in the PDP page and wondering if its actually supported by Spartacus 6.5.
I don't see any specific documantation about it but I can see a  attribute in the Spartacus code which makes me believe that video files are supported. But I get a error **'cx-video' is not a known element: "If 'cx-video' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module."**
Do I have to import anything else in my modules to get it to work? normal images are working fine with .
Are video files supported by Spartacus and where can I get any documentation or sample example of it.